# How to convert a VisualElementRenderer from XF to Maui Handlers

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui, .net-maui

I have a Custom Renderer in my Xamarin Forms application that I need to convert to Maui Handler.

So I have a VisualElementRenderer which is something like below:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CardsView), typeof(CardsViewRenderer))]
namespace CardView
{
    [Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
    public class CardsViewRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<CardsView>
    {
    }
}
```

Where `CardsView` is derived from `AbsoluteLayout`.

Now, I am trying to convert this to Maui but I am not able to find a `VisualElementHandler` that would replace `VisualElementRenderer`. If this is not the case what would my Handler Inherit from since I don't have a PlatformView to pass into my ViewHandler, I am not sure what the PlatformView would be in this case.

As of right now, this is what I have came up with

```
public partial class CardsViewHandler : ViewHandler<CardsView,??Not sure??>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the reosurce code and found there was no handler for the `AbsoluteLayout`. But the `AbsoluteLayout` is inherited from the `Layout` which has a `LayoutHandler`.

And the `LayoutHandler` will return the `ViewGroup` for android and the `UIView` for the ios when the instance of the `Layout` in the Maui is created. So you can try to use the following first line code for the ios and the second line code for the android.

```
public partial class CardsViewHandler : ViewHandler<CardsView,LayoutView>
  //LayoutView is inherited from the MauiView which is inherited from the UIKit.UIView
public partial class CardsViewHandler : ViewHandler<CardsView,LayoutGroup>
  //LayoutGroup is inherited from Android.Views.ViewGroup
```

In addition, you can also use the custom renderer in the maui according to [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Using-Custom-Renderers-in-.NET-MAUI).

Comment: FYI this did not work